# loop cycle to get a column from each dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I would need help analyzing 300 files and obtaining only one column from each of them. In the end I will have to create a final dataframe with the sum of all the columns. To do this I need to write a loop, but I don't know how to do it. I really need to learn loop cycles, maybe starting with something easier :D

```
y= grangeobject
```

loop cycle for 300 files:

```
library(data.table)
df= fread("myfile.bed.gz")
df= df[,c(1:3)]
colnames(df) <- c("seqnames", "chromStart", "chromEnd")
df1= makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)
remove(df)
h1=as.data.frame(countOverlaps(y, df1))
```

I need to do this again for `df2, df3, df4,....df300`, then I want to merge all the object in one data frame:

```
 X= as.matrix(cbind(h1,h2,h3,....h300))
colnames(X) = c(h1,h2,h3,....h300)
```

could you help me?

Comment: I seriously doubt you need to convert to data.frame after using fread - a data.table is also a data.frame.

Comment: Yes, I can skip the passage data.frame, I just need to take only the first three column of each file

Answer (score 1):

Just as a start, let me know if this is getting closer to what you want.

```
library(data.table)

df <- fread("myfile.bed.gz")
df[, 3:length(names(df)) := NULL] #since you do remove(df) anyway
setnames(df, c("seqnames", "chromStart", "chromEnd")) 

# Not sure what these do
df1 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)
h1 <- as.data.frame(countOverlaps(y, df1))
```

And then the merge could be something like

```
do.call(cbind, sapply(paste0("h",1:300), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
```

Comment: Yes, that Is exactly what I want, but since I have to do this for 300 files  I Need to write a for cycle because I have to remove dataframes and take only the object h1,h2,h3, etc. that Is Just One column, and bind all the h column to have as final output only the dataframe with 300 column and the same Number of rows

Comment: just an appoint it should be df[, 4:length(names(df)) := NULL]